# ActionScript: How read only part of local file?

Tags: actionscript-3

How read only part of local file? So that not to load the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AIR you can use the [`readBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes%28%29) method of the `FileStream` API to specify an offset of the file where you want to start reading.

For a SWF that is running in the browser, the only method in the Flash Player 10 is the [`load()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load%28%29) method of the `FileReference` class and that one doesn't allow you to specify an offset.